# How to relate each radio button to an object when mapping them

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make an app that has questions about random things, each one with different categories. The user just need to choose between "yes" or "no", very simple.

I have an array of objects that have category and question for each object,

```
const questionsArray = [
    {
        category: 'sports',
        question: 'Do you practice soccer?'
    },
    {
        category: 'sports',
        question: 'Do you practice baseball?'
    },
    {
        category: 'routine',
        question: 'Do you like to watch movies?'
    },
    {
        category: 'routine',
        question: 'Do you like to play video games?'
    },
    {
        category: 'food',
        question: 'Do you like pasta?'
    },
    {
        category: 'food',
        question: 'Do you like cake?'
    },
]
```

In here I'm looping through this array and showing the user the questions,

```
{questionsArray.map((data, i) => (
    <>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
            {i + 1} - {data.question}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 10 }}>
            {data.atividades}
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.radioButtonContainer}>
            <RadioButton
                value="yes"
                color="#fff"
                uncheckedColor="#fff"
                status={checked === "yes" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                onPress={e => setChecked("yes")}
            />
            <Text style={styles.radioText}>Yes </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.radioButtonContainer}>
            <RadioButton
                value="no"
                color="#fff"
                uncheckedColor="#fff"
                status={checked === "no" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                onPress={() => setChecked("no")}
            />
            <Text style={styles.radioText}>No </Text>
        </View>
    </>
))}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to relate each radio button with a question. I'm using this library for the radio button https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button.html

The current behavior is when I change one radio button all of them change, which makes sense because they're using the same state.

In the end when the user press the **submit answers** button, I want a JSON like this as an output, that shows how many "yes" answers for each category:

```
{
 "result": {
    "sports": 1,
    "routine": 1,
    "food": 2
   } 
}
```

Here is the full code: https://snack.expo.io/UhoiXh4ri

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use nested arrays? Like, you have a category, then under it - you have an array of category related questions. Repeat the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you group the radio buttons based on their `name` attribute it should work.

Add `name={data.category}` to both radio buttons